# How to print files with same month of modification using directory in c?

Tags: c, file, date, directory

I'm making a code where it gets the directory of a folder with txt files in it then it prints out all the txt files with the same month of creation/last modification.

For example, if the user types 'JANUARY', the program will print out all the names of files created/last modified in January.

This is my code but it's not working.

```
DIR *da; 
struct dirent *ep;  
struct stat attrib;  

da = opendir ("./"); 
if (da != NULL)  
{
    while (ep = readdir (da)) 
    {
    while ((ep = readdir (da)) != NULL) 
    {
        const size_t len = strlen(ep->d_name);    

            if (len > 4                    && 
            ep->d_name[len - 4] == '.' &&
            ep->d_name[len - 3] == 'T' &&
            ep->d_name[len - 2] == 'X' &&
            ep->d_name[len - 1] == 'T') {

                stat(ep->d_name, &attrib); 

                strftime(month, MAX_SIZE, "%m", localtime(&(attrib.st_ctime)));

                comp = strcmp(month,input);
                if(comp == 0) {
                    printf ("%s\n", ep->d_name);
                }   
            } 
       } 
    closedir (da);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: Which error you are getting?

Comment: what is the _use_ of `(void)` in `(void) closedir (da);`?

Comment: The doubly nested `while` loop is probably wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are closing the directory stream in wrong place. You are closing that in the inner while but you have to close that after the outer while.

```
if (da != NULL) 
{
 while (ep = readdir (da)) 
   while ((ep = readdir (da)) != NULL)
   {
    const size_t len = strlen(ep->d_name);   

    if (len > 4                    &&
        ep->d_name[len - 4] == '.' &&
        ep->d_name[len - 3] == 't' &&
        ep->d_name[len - 2] == 'x' &&
        ep->d_name[len - 1] == 't') {

            stat(ep->d_name, &attrib); 
            foo = localtime(&(attrib.st_mtime));

            if(foo->tm_mon+1 == 1) {


             printf ("%s\n", ep->d_name);
                }
        }
   }
 closedir (da); 
}
```

After that while checking the condition in a if you can use the strcmp function.

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);

if ( strcmp(ep->d_name+(len-4),".txt") ==0 ){ 
...
}
```